# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I just moved a user from one 22.04 computer to another which now has two users, by creating the user, and then copying /home/user

My problem is that the gnome-terminal will not start. By installing another terminal program I see this error:

```
$ gnome-terminal 
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

After some searching I found that mixing some other posts, I can start gnome-terminal using this commandline, but it take a lot of time!

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8" /usr/bin/dbus-launch /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

I have tried to regenerate locale without luck.

The original user on the PC has no problems starting, but the new one has. Can it be a problem that before moving, the new user had the same user id as the original user on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

The copied files and directories in the home directory of the new user all should be correctly owned by that new user. You only mentioned that you copied the files. Make sure, also, to recursively change ownership of all files copied to the home folder of the new user, including especially the hidden files and directories.

Comment: I used tar to copy the files, and unpacked with the destination user id. And I just verified that there were no conflicts.